# I am getting error running function in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that I need to call from html. However, the way I have the call at the moment, it is causing typeError. Can someone show me how run this function: splitboxes(); in my html markup.

The function is declared earlier and works if I run just 'splitboxes', but need to call it as a function.

Thank you

```
$("html").append("<div id='dialog-success' />");
          var dialogSuccess = $("#dialog-success");
           dialogSuccess.html('<br />Here the details of your submitted intake ' + 
            '<br /><b><font color="green">' + depts + '</font></b><br />' + splitboxes(); + 
             ' This entry was successfully submitted to the database.<br />Thank you.');
```

Comment: remove the ; after the `splitboxes()`

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:

```
...+ splitboxes(); + ...
```

to

```
...+ splitboxes() + ...
```

Please use IDE to do your coding. It saves you aloooooot of headache :)

Comment: My IDE tells me the syntax error the moment I pasted the OP's code in. IDE is a tool, use one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("html").prepend("<div id='dialog-success' />");
 var dialogSuccess = $("#dialog-success");
dialogSuccess.html('<br />Here the details of your submitted intake <br /><b><font color="green">depts</font></b><br />' + splitboxes()+' This entry was successfully submitted to the database.<br />Thank you.');

function splitboxes(){
return "<i>output from splitboxes() function</i>";
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

just remove `;` from `+ splitboxes(); +`  here is the code and output